# Excel does not launch when not logged in

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

This is the sequesnce of events I am trying to achieve:
Scheduled Task- runs at the same time everyday and launches a VBScript
VBScript Launches Excel Workbook and runs a Macro. Here is the snippet-

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open (xlFilePath,0,False)
xlApp.Run "Main"
```

Now the problem is if I run the task manually, It runs fine. When I run the scheduled task when I am not logged on to the server, it does not launch excel. What do I have to change in the code above to launch excel when no user is logged on? I have set Excel Macro security to Low.

Excel 2003 and Windows Server2003 64

Comment: do you know if Excel opens up fine? Meaning the VBScript runs, just not the VBA macro?

Comment: Excel doesn't open. I ran another VBScript to check if excel is running and I launched it at the same time as the scheduled task and it cannot find excel.exe in the processes.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [MS Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) - according to this, Office apps need an UI to run.

Thus, try using any user but the system user:

> For example, code that is started by Task Scheduler under the SYSTEM account runs in the same environment as "server-side" ASP code or as DCOM code. Therefore, many of the issues that this article describes may occur.

Also, try to call `Main` from the Workbook_Open event in the Excel file instead of `xlApp.Run "Main"`...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is already resolved, but I got the problem and resolved with the below steps.

Create the below folder(s)

(32Bit, always) C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

(64Bit) above folder and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

This will resolve the issue if you are running with system account.

Comment: Thank you very much. After a 14 hours' shotgun debugging, I came upon your answer and it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an option to use a username when running the task as well as have the task run whether the user is logged on or not.  Here's an example from Windows Server 2008:

[image]

Comment: This option does not exist in 2003. And anyways, the task does launch when I am not logged in, It's excel that's having problems.

Comment: @KailasDeshpande my apologies for that. I notice the other answer talks about the need for a UI in Excel. that's a bummer. I'm not sure what you could do besides re-writing the program in vbscript or vb.net or the like. If you do find a solution I'd be curious to know what you did. Good luck!